# Adding array into POST parameters C#

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net, dictionary

I want to add something like this (shown below) into my POST parameters:

```
{"DaysBefore": 5,
"IdList": [
5,
9,
13,
14
 ],
"pId": 1,
"mId": 1
}
```

I have a Dictionary like this:

```
var postData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
postData.Add("IdList","b")
```

Insted of `b` how can I add [
5,
9,
13,
14
] there?

I want to send the `Generic.List()` to the backend using C#

Comment: Looks like you need to post a JSON object; you should use a JSON serialiser instead of a dictionary.

Comment: What you posted is a single JSON document, not multiple query parameters. It's an *object* whose `IdList` property contains a numeric array. There's no "generic list" involved

Answer (score 0):

I would parse it as Json.  There's no need to pull the array in as a string and then have to parse that out to an int list.

```
    public static void Main()
{
        var foo = @"{""DaysBefore"": 5,
            ""IdList"": [
            5,
            9,
            13,
            14
             ],
            ""pId"": 1,
            ""mId"": 1
            }";
            
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(foo);
    
    Console.WriteLine("DaysBefore: " + result.DaysBefore);
    Console.WriteLine("idList: " + String.Join(", ", result.idList));
    Console.WriteLine("mId: " + result.mId);
    Console.WriteLine("pId: " + result.pId);

}
                                           
public class Data
{
    public string DaysBefore {get; set;}
    public List<int> idList{ get; set;}
    public int pId {get; set;}
    public int mId {get; set;}
}
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1obyGI)